# Why is Oracle cannot save some characters as given from the hibernate but changing it to ¿

Tags: oracle, spring-boot, hibernate, character-encoding

I am trying to save this value from Spring boot to a `NVARCHAR2` field in a table in Oracle Database:

```
Lyli’anna
```

I expected Oracle to save that entire value. However, this is the value I got whether selecting with sqldeveloper or getting that value in my spring application:

```
Lyli¿anna
```

Is there any way to fix this issue without modifying the data/value to be inserted to the database?? Mind to share it in detail?

---

Update:

I have tried added the JVM run Option with `-Duser.encoding=UTF8`,
added these on the datasource configuration:

```
        hibernateProperties.put("hibernate.connection.characterEncoding", "utf8");
        hibernateProperties.put("hibernate.connection.CharSet", "utf8");
        hibernateProperties.put("hibernate.connection.useUnicode", true);
        hibernateProperties.put(OracleConnection.CONNECTION_PROPERTY_DEFAULTNCHAR, "true");
        hibernateProperties.put("hibernate.connection.defaultNChar", true);
```

But same thing still happened.

Comment: Check the database national character set, and how you are querying the data, and the character set used by your application and SQL Developer. It looks like you just have a mismatch somewhere. You can `dump()` the value in the column to verify what is actually stored.

Comment: @AlexPoole Do you mean `select dump('’') from dual;` ?

Comment: @AlexPoole Here is it `Typ=96 Len=9: 76,121,108,105,191,97,110,110,97` The quote mark seems to be that `191`. When I searched the  ascii 191, it;'s the inverted question mark.

Comment: `select dump(your_column, 1016) from your table where ...` to see what is stored. That will tell you if the issue is during the insert, or (more likely) how you are querying.

Comment: How did you insert the data?

Comment: @AlexPoole This is it : Typ=1 Len=18 CharacterSet=AL16UTF16: 0,4c,0,79,0,6c,0,69,0,27,0,61,0,6e,0,6e,0,61

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit That data was inserted by a backend service built with Java-Spring Boot-Hibernate. It seems nothing strange on the service log when saving

Answer (score 1):

As you found out already the data **is really** `Lyli¿anna`. So, it is not a problem of displaying it or a problem with the font.

Spring boot/hibernate are Java/JDBC based have a look at [Database JDBC Developer's Guide - Globalization Support](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/JJDBC/global.htm#JJDBC28643).

I am not familiar with Java, as a first try I would suggest to set

```
JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS=-Duser.encoding=UTF8 (or 'UTF-8'?)
```

Or whatever character set which is used by your application.

Comment: Thank you for your response. However, I still got the same thing after I put that on JVM options and set up the UTF8 on the charset and character encoding on datasource configuration.

Comment: Is your application really using UTF-8? I guess, it does not.

Comment: Well, I saw it was fine on the application log when receiving that input and even sending that towards another API. However, it got changed when it was saved on database.